# Square root of particular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have stumbled upon a problem where I need the square root of the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0 & x_1\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & x_{n-1} \\
x_1 & \cdots & x_{n-1} & x_n
\end{bmatrix}

It would be nice if the matrix square root wasn’t too complicated. Since this matrix has rank 2, I believe that a decomposition could indeed be quite simple. I am not able to verify this however, and would appreciate a little hint.

Comment: If the ground field is real, the matrix has not any real square root unless $x_1=\cdots=x_{n-1}=0$ and $x_n\ge0$.

Comment: I see, thanks. It may be interesting to not only allow for square roots $B$ such that $A = BB$, but also any factorization such that $A = B B^T$ (where $B$ is allowed to have any dimension). Would this change anything?

Comment: No, it would’t. The matrix is indefinite (again, unless $x_1=\cdots=x_n=0$ and $x_n\ge0$). It cannot possibly be a Gram matrix.

Comment: @user1551 I don't think you are right.
This matrix is real and symmetric, so, it is diagonalisable and has all real eigvenvalues (the eigenvalues are $n-2$ zeros and 2 real values $val1, val2$, $\{ 0,0,0,0,..,0, val1, val2 \}$, I checked with Mathematica already): $$M:= P^T DP$$
So, $M= H^T H$ where $H = P^T D^{1/2}$
The problem here is just to find the eigenvector matrix $P$ and the eigenvalues

Comment: @NN2 Consider e.g. $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$. It cannot be written as $B^2$ or $B^TB$ for some real square matrix $B$, because $\det(A)<0$ but $\det(B^2)=\det(B^TB)=\det(B)^2\ge0$. The trouble here is that $A$ has a negative eigenvalue.

Comment: @user1551 Ah yes, you are right. One of the two 'non-zeros' eigenvalues is negative. So, the squareroot is complex number.

Comment: @Kristan I'm not sure if this would be useful to you, but you could write this matrix in the form $A = BDB^T$ where $B$ has shape $n \times 2$ and $D$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $1,-1$.